# How to store msgbox value from different sheets into one sheet

Tags: vba

I want to store multiple msgbox value based on the search from different sheets into one sheet with defined range.

I couldn't able to proceed with the below code using.

```
Private Sub SearchData()
    Dim Wsheet As Worksheet, myCounter
    Dim Loc As Range
    Dim sMsg As String
    Dim strName As String
    On Error Resume Next
    strName = InputBox("Please enter the text you are searching for")
    If strName = "" Then Exit Sub
    For Each Wsheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With Wsheet.UsedRange
            Set Loc = .Cells.Find(What:=strName)

            If Not Loc Is Nothing Then

                sMsg = MsgBox("Value is found  in " & Wsheet.Name)
                If MsgBox(sMsg) = vbOK Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Instructions").Range("K14").Value = sMsg
                    myCounter = 1
                    Set Loc = .FindNext(Loc)

            End If
        End With
    Next
    If myCounter = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Value not present in this workbook")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Instructions").Range("K14").Value = sMsg` here is your problem... You are always saving the `MsgBox`on the same cell so you end up with the last one.

Comment: Just some advice: never use On Error Resume Next like this. Jump over a line if you have to (but better to handle the error with proper "If"), and then restore error alerts:

    If MsgBox(sMsg) = vbOK Then
                    On Error Resume Next 'jump over line causing trouble
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Instructions").Range("K14").Value = sMsg
                    On Error GoTo 0 'restore error alerts after troublesome line
                    myCounter = 1
                    Set Loc = .FindNext(Loc)
    End If

This will help you a lot of headache in the future.

Comment: i am not getting the solution.. can you please extend the solution?.. i want to store the msgbox value for each sheet against where each value automatically store against each sheetname value.

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing `End If` in the middle of your code.

```
If MsgBox(sMsg) = vbOK Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Instructions").Range("K14").Value = sMsg
    myCounter = 1
    Set Loc = .FindNext(Loc)
End If '<-- Missing
```

Comment: what's the solution in this case? My query is to store the msgbox value of each sheet in a different sheet and that also store the sheetname against that value.